# How to maintain sorting of a table that is done using <display tag> after going to next page and then coming back on same

Tags: jsp, struts, jsp-tags, struts-1

I have a jsp that contains following code:

```
  <display:table onclick="myAction.do?method=displayDetails" sort="list" name="${UCForm.liste}" defaultsort="1" defaultorder="descending" pagesize="40" export="true" requestURI="myAction.do?method=recherche" decorator="web.displaytag.TableDecorator" id="listeId"> <display:setProperty name="export.csv.filename" value="abc.csv" /> <display:column property="abcName" title="Name" sortable="true" headerClass="sortable"/> <display:column title="VL" sortable="true" headerClass= "sortable" > <c:if test="${listeId.blocagevl eq 1}"><img src="img/Lock.png" height="10" width="10"/></c:if></display:column> </display:table>
```

What I want here is when the user clicks on any column to sort table and goes on some next screen and then come back on this screen then the sorting should be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Each column header has a link that points to the current page with a query string which is required for doing the sort.

One way to keep the table sorted when the user comes back is to save the query string in the session each time the user clicks on a header. In the action that loads the page check if the user has stored the query string and redirect accordingly.